# Unable to see the output while recording the key strokes using jnativeHook

Tags: java

I'm trying to record the keystrokes when ever i perform some key events like left,right,move,press,release etc.Initially when i wrote the code and compiled it i was able to record the key strokes.However,When i compiled after a little bit of code indentation it is showing the following statement

```
  Process finished with exit code 0
```

Below posted is my code:

```
public class key_logger implements NativeKeyListener {

public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

          if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
          {

               GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
           }

  }

public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

}

public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    System.out.println("Key Typed: " + e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();

    }

    catch (NativeHookException ex) {

        System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");

        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        System.exit(1);
    }

    //Construct the example object and initialze native hook.
    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new key_logger());
}
  }
```

Comment: The JVM will exit when the only threads left running are daemon threads.  It's likely that once the `main` exits, the application is been terminated.  Have you considered creating a "escape" key sequence which your key logger would listen for and then set an exit state which you can monitor, maybe using a Object lock of some kind?

Comment: Maybe escape is stuck? Try removing `GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();`

Comment: @ChrisK  i've done it but still the error is persisting

Comment: Your code works for me on Windows 8 with jnativehook 2.0.0-RC5.

Comment: @ChrisK even mine is the same OS

Comment: Maybe you have another jnativehook process running already? I would try restarting your computer.

Comment: @ChrisK  The error is whenver i tried to end the program..i did not hit  escape to end it...because of which i assume i could have got this problem.It can be also understood that the registered hook hasnot been closed properly!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82764/discussion-between-mohan-babu-and-chris-k).

Comment: Works okay for me (2.0.2).  May consider adding a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) which performs the unregister process